# HCL @Command([MailForward]) Command issue

Tags: lotus-notes, forward, lotus-formula

Since last Friday I was not able to forward a document as email on a database using HCL Notes formula @command. The email is forward, but no content is available, but in the document the content exist. The unique way to forward with content is using the right click then choosing Forward.

Here are the ones I tried to use:

1. From HCL email
   `@SetEnvironment("fwdID"; @NoteID); @Command([MailForward])`
2. From HCL email
   `@Command( [MailForwardAsAttachment] )`

Any help I appreciate.

[image: Image using system button forward]

[image: Image sing right click]

Comment: Does this happen for EVERY mail or only for some?

Comment: That happens when someone click forward button, for all documents. This is a database, not an inbox.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is the ACL setting "Replicate or copy documents". If users do not have this box checked in the ACL entry that grants them access, they will be unable to forward documents from the database.

[image: ACL dialog box]

Comment: All users have that attribute checked. Note that this is the results, using the Fwd system button and using the right click choosing Forward function. I just updated the original post to show those images.

Comment: I remember an old bug. Lotus said it wasn't a bug. I disagree. Check the documents that the users are trying to forward and see if they have a $KeepPrivate item shown in the scrolling list in the Document Properties dialog. This item stops all users from copying or forwarding. It gets added to any document created or edited by a user who doesn't have that checkmark, so if one user ran an agent, it could stop all users. I know you said that all users have it checked, but let's rule it out by checking. Someone could have had it unchecked previously.

Comment: Hi Richard, sorry for the delay, I had few issues to solve in another database. But I noted that there is no field with that $KeepPrivate ...